# Find the average value of n largest in a month, but day has to be unique (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

How can I find the average value of n largest values in a month, but day has to be unique?

I do have a timestamp column as well, but I would guess making columns of them is the way to go?

I tried `df['peak_avg'] = df.groupby(['month', 'day'])['value'].transform(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).mean())`, but this takes the average of the three largest days.

| month | day | value | peak_avg (expected) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 35 | 35 |
| 1 | 1 | 30 | 35 |
| 2 | 1 | 34 | 28.5 |
| 2 | 2 | 23 | 28.5 |
| 3 | 1 | 98 | 97 |
| 3 | 2 | 96. | 97 |

Comment: average of 98, 98, and 35 in this example?  could you give us what is the expected output?

Comment: Oh, sorry, yeah that didn't make sense. Fixed it now.

Comment: So for all rows, except the first two, the average will be calculated grouped by month and day since day is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can drop the duplicate in `month` and `day` columns and at last fill them

```py
df['peak_avg'] = (df.sort_values(['month', 'day', 'value'], ascending=[True, True, False])
                  .drop_duplicates(['month', 'day'])
                  .groupby(['month'])['value']
                  .transform(lambda x: x.head(3).mean()))
df['peak_avg'] = df.groupby(['month', 'day'])['peak_avg'].apply(lambda g: g.ffill().bfill())
```

```
print(df)

   month  day  value  peak_avg
0      1    1     35      35.0
1      1    1     12      35.0
2      2    1     34      28.5
3      2    3     23      28.5
4      3    1     98      98.0
5      3    2     98      98.0
```

Comment: I wonder if `.drop_duplicates()` is guaranteed to use max day value?

Comment: @Marat It doesn't, it keeps first value by default. But max day value can be achieved by sorting before `drop_duplicates`.

Comment: if you're about to sort it by value anyway, maybe add day to sorting and use `.head(3)` instead of `.transform(...)` then? That'd be a bit more concise/readable IMO

Comment: Yes, I think sorting is needed, at least for my real dataset. Is `sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)` correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can first derive max value for a day and you should group only by `month`, since you want to take average of month.

```py
df['max_value'] = df.groupby(['month', 'day']).value.transform(max)

df['peak_avg'] = df.groupby('month').value.transform(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

`Pivot` the dataframe with aggfunc `max`, then sort and select the top three columns and use `nanmean` along columns axis to calculate average

```
s = df.pivot_table('value', 'month', 'day', 'max')
s['avg'] = np.nanmean(np.sort(-s, 1)[:, :3] * -1, 1)
df['avg'] = df['month'].map(s['avg'])
```

---

```
   month  day  value  peak_avg (expected)   avg
0      1    1   35.0                 35.0  35.0
1      1    1   30.0                 35.0  35.0
2      2    1   34.0                 28.5  28.5
3      2    2   23.0                 28.5  28.5
4      3    1   98.0                 97.0  97.0
5      3    2   96.0                 97.0  97.0
```

Comment: will you explain your code and why map works to give the correct results